# Update Metadata of Solana NFT Collection

Tags: metadata, blockchain, solana, nft

So, I had launched a NFT Collection on the Solana Blockchain recently, and it got fully sold out.

But I just realised that the royalties i.e. the `seller_fee_basis_points` are not according to my requirement.

So I wanted to know how could I update the metadata so that I can change the amount of royalties a creator gets for all the NFTs in the minted collection:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Token Metadata program supports metadata update, see code [here](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/master/token-metadata/program/src/processor.rs#L101=), however, it requires:

- The metadata to be **[mutable](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/master/token-metadata/program/src/processor.rs#L340=)**
- The **[update authority to sign](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/master/token-metadata/program/src/utils.rs#L195=)**

Comment: Is there any guide or something which shows the process?